# How do I put this into a working code to validate user input (Java)?

Tags: java, eclipse, validation, while-loop

I am beginner programmer. I am trying to write a code with this requirement that user input must be number 1-20 and also that it is not a letter.

Requirement on my code:

- while loop i.e while(true)
- isDigit()

I started with this code, but I don't know how to implement the isDigit method. I assume it has to be nested within the while loop.

```
    while(input < 1 || input > 20){
        System.out.println("Invalid number! Try again.");
        input = s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine();
    }
    return input;
}
```

I have tried using "if" statement and using another "while" loop but it didn't work. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your while condition is incorrect, `while(input < 1 || input > 20)` it is checking if number is less than 1 and greater than 20,

This problem has two parts, 1. check if input is valid number , 2. check if number is in range

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean validInput = false;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter valid number ");
            // get user input
            String input =  sc.nextLine();

            if(isDigit(input)) {
                int inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(input);
                //check if number is in the range of 1 to 20
                boolean isInRange = (inputNumber > 1) && (inputNumber < 20);
                validInput  = true;
                if(isInRange) {
                    System.out.println(input+" is valid Number and in the range of 1 to 20");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(input+" is valid Number But Not in the range of 1 to 20");
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(input+" is invalid Number");
            }
        }
        while (!validInput ); // continues untill valid input is entered

    }
```

Here `isDigit` method uses regular expresssion `[0-9]` to check if character is in the range of 0 to 9, you can check more on regular expressions here https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_regex.asp

```
    //check if input is valid number
    public static boolean isDigit(String input) {

        if (input == null || input.length() < 0)
            return false;
        input = input.trim();
        if ("".equals(input))
            return false;
        if (input.startsWith("-")) {
            return input.substring(1).matches("[0-9]*");
        } else {
            return input.matches("[0-9]*");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Given the original poster is a novice Java developer it might be nice to explain that this solution uses Regular Expressions :)

Comment: @Gavin updated answer to include regular expressions details

Answer (score 0):

I've extended your `while()` to have extra logic to check if entered input is numeric value using `isNumeric()` provided by StringUtils. This function checks if the CharSequence contains only Unicode digits and hence reducing the complexity of the code having to check numeric value explicitly.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isNumeric;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int result = isDigit();
        System.out.println("Result is: " + result);
    }

    public static int isDigit() {
        // Create a Scanner object
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        // Accept input in String
        String input = s.next();

        /**
         * Check if input is numeric and between 1 and 20.
         * Otherwise, accept new input from user.
         */
        while (!isNumeric(String.valueOf(input))
            || Integer.parseInt(input) < 1 || Integer.parseInt(input) > 20) {
            System.out.println("Invalid number! Range should be between 1 and 20. Try     again.");
            input = s.next();
            s.nextLine();
        }

        // Return numeric value which is between 1 and 20
        return Integer.parseInt(input);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter number
30
Invalid number! Range should be between 1 and 20. Try again.
-10
Invalid number! Range should be between 1 and 20. Try again.
abc
Invalid number! Range should be between 1 and 20. Try again.
10
Result is: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using two static functions to

1. Find the inputted number is integer or not [isInteger] and
2. To force the user to input a number between 1 and 20.

As you are an beginner, I did not use regular expression while checking the user input is number.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter an integer number between 1 and 20");
    String userInput = scanner.nextLine();

    int requiredInput = validateAndGetNumber(userInput);

    /*
      Now, do whatever you want to do with this requiredInput
    */
}

public static int validateAndGetNumber(String input) {
        
    if (isInteger(input)) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(input);

        if (num >= 1 && num <= 20) 
            return num;
        else {
            System.out.println("Number is not in range 1-20. Please try again.");
            input = scanner.nextLine();
            return validateAndGetNumber(input);
        }
    }
        
    System.out.println("Input is not an integer number. Please try again.");
    input = scanner.nextLine();
    return validateAndGetNumber(input);
}

public static boolean isInteger(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return false;
    }
    int length = str.length();
    if (length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int i = 0;
    if (str.charAt(0) == '-') {
       System.out.println("Negative value is invalid for this property.");
       return false;
    }

    for (; i < length; i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);

        if ((c < '0' || c > '9') && c != '-') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```